# Is there a list of kanji ordered by usage in novels?

Tags: kanji, resources

I have found many lists of kanji ordered by their usage in newspapers, but are there any lists that order by their usage in novels and other fictional material?

This might be useful to have because if someone wanted to be able to read Japanese novels well, they could study the kanji in the list.

Comment: Here are some frequency lists that don't meet your criteria: The Agency for Cultural Affairs list: http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/bunkasingi/kanji_24/pdf/sanko_3.pdf  Here's one based on modified Wikipedia data: http://shang.kapsi.fi/kanji/  And another newspaper-based one: http://www.tidraso.co.uk/kanji_frequency.html  And based on a web corpus: http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/frqc/internet-jp.num  This one IS based on novels, but is based on attempted lexical chunking rather than individual kanji: http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/index.php?entry=1222520260

Comment: I'm in favor of resource questions being allowed here, but... isn't this a resource question? Why are people not jumping on this like usual?
Edit: I didn't notice how crazy old this is. Probably predates the no-resource-questions rule.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

https://foosoft.net/projects/kanji-frequency/

Comment: Interesting that Heisig misses #66 (俺) and #158 (誰).

Answer (score 9):

I managed to collect the data of kanji usage frequencies from various sources:

- Japanese Wikipedia's snapshot
- About 12900 files from [Aozora Bunko](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/) - these are mostly novels, I believe
- Public tweets from Twitter's Streaming API
- Online news articles from various sources

You can find it [here](http://scriptin.github.io/kanji-frequency/). The one you're looking for is "Aozora". There are files in JSON format in [the repository](https://github.com/scriptin/kanji-frequency). Each file contains JSON table, format is described in [README.md](https://github.com/scriptin/kanji-frequency/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Funny that 笑 is #1 on Twitter!